# Proving whether the limit of a sequence will always converge to 0?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $(b_{n})$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $0<(b_{n})<1$. And let Let $(a_{n})$ be a sequence of real numbers defined by $a_{n+1}=a_{n}b_{n}$ where $a_{1}=1$.
>   Is it always true that $lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n}=0$?

I know that $a_{n}=b_{1}b_{2}...b_{n-1}$. I also know that it is bounded below by zero and is strictly decreasing. I should use the MCT somehow, but I'm stuck.

Since, I want to prove that the limit is always 0.

$|a_{n}-0|=|\frac{c_{1}...c_{n-1}}{d_{1}...d_{n-1}}-0|<\epsilon$, where $b_{n}=\frac{c_{n}}{d_{n}}$.

Comment: Is every monotonic decreasing seqence converging to $0$? Use the answer to construct $\left(b_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n\rightarrow a$ with $a_1=1$ be monotonic decreasing with $a>0.$ Now consider $b_n:=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. Clearly $b_n$ is in $\left(0,1\right).$
Thus the answer is no.

Comment: How does  limit of $b_{n}$ as $n$ goes to infinity $!=0$ mean than $a_{n}$ doesn't always converge to 0.

Comment: @Achro: See, Max assumes $a_n\to a \ne 0$, then constructs appropriate $(b_n)$ which gives the assumed $(a_n)$. This is a way to explicitly construct a counterexample to the given conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

This is a somewhat more explicit answer than Mr. Max's excellent answer. Let $a_1=1$ and $$(b_n)=(\frac 1{1.9},\frac {1.9}{1.99}, \frac {1.99}{1.999},...)$$
Clearly, each $b_n\in(0,1)$ and 
$$
a_n=\frac 1{1.99...9}
$$ 
where there are in total of $n-1$ nines. Therefore $a_n\to \frac 12 \ne 0$.